# Entity Framework and row level security for AD Groups

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a project where we want to achieve the following:

Let's say we have a table named products:

```
[Id] [Title] [Description] [AccessRights]
```

Now what we want to do is create a method that returns an IQueryable that exposes the data of this table only where a certain user (an input parameter) is in the group under the AccessRights column.

So let's say we have a user Devedse and a user TestMan. The user Devedse is in the group 'PowerUsers'. Where the user TestMan is not. And we would like to request all products for the user TestMan, we should not get any products with the AccessRight 'PowerUsers'.

Now this is something we can off course implement in C# but we would rather implement this using a function in SQL so we don't have to retrieve all data first before determining what rows are accessible to the user.

So something like this:

```
public IQueryable GetProducts(string user)
{
    return dbContext.Products.ExecuteStoredProcedure(user);
}
```

We currently implemented this using the IS_MEMBER() function in a function which is then exposed through a view. Sadly this does not support an input (and neither does a View support an input parameter). The IS_MEMBER function will simply check if the current user is a member of this group, thus requiring us to use either impersonation or EXECUTE AS. (Which then require all domain users basically to have read access on the database. Something I would rather not do).

Does anyone have an idea how we can achieve this?

Edit: It's also important that the IQueryable we expose can still be used with additional where queries. (The way LINQ normally deffers execution for LINQ queries on an IQueryable so that the final SQL query won't have to first obtain all data before processing it).

Edit2: Thinking of it, the most ideal situation would be where EntityFramework would generate some kind of SQL like:

```
select * from Products WHERE @param1.IsMemberOf(AccessRights)
```

I am not sure if this is even possible though?

Comment: When you run a linq to entities query it will not return a full list of all users and then filter the results it will run a normal sql query. Why can you not do this as a linq to entity query ?